# Path-Finding BFS Implementation

Tags: java, algorithm, breadth-first-search

I discovered this on GitHub: https://github.com/greerviau/Path-Finding, which is a program that visualizes 2 algorithms (Dijkstra and A*). I want to implement BFS into the program. Am I doing this right? Here's my code:

```
public void BreadthFirst() {
            ArrayList<Node> priority = new ArrayList<Node>();
            Node currentNode = null;
            priority.add(map[startx][starty]);
            while(solving){
                if(priority.size() <= 0){
                    solving = false;
                    break;
                }
                int hops = priority.get(0).getHops()+1;
                ArrayList<Node> explored = exploreNeighbors(priority.get(0),hops);
                if(explored.size() > 0){
                    currentNode = priority.remove(0);
                    if(currentNode.equals(map[finishx][finishy])){
                        solving = false;
                        continue;
                    }
                    else {
                        for(int i = 0; i < explored.size(); i++){
                            priority.add(explored.get(i));
                            Update();
                            delay();
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    priority.remove(0);
                }
            }
        }
```

Can somebody help? Thank you!

**UPDATE**

I changed my code to:

```
public void BreadthFirst() {
            ArrayList<Node> priority = new ArrayList<Node>();
            priority.add(map[startx][starty]);
            while(solving) {
                if(priority.size() <= 0) {
                    solving = false;
                    break;
                }
                int hops = priority.get(0).getHops()+1;
                ArrayList<Node> explored = exploreNeighbors1(priority.get(0), hops);
                if(explored.size() > 0) {
                    priority.remove(0);
                    priority.addAll(explored);
                    Update();
                    delay();
                } else {
                    priority.remove(0);
                }
            }
        }
```

and made exploreNeighbors1 for BFS:

```
public ArrayList<Node> exploreNeighbors1(Node current, int hops) {  //EXPLORE NEIGHBORS
            ArrayList<Node> explored = new ArrayList<Node>();   //LIST OF NODES THAT HAVE BEEN EXPLORED
            for(int a = -1; a <= 1; a++) {
                for(int b = -1; b <= 1; b++) {
                    int xbound = current.getX(); 
                    int ybound = current.getY()+b;
                    if((xbound > -1 && xbound < cells) && (ybound > -1 && ybound < cells)) {    //MAKES SURE THE NODE IS NOT OUTSIDE THE GRID
                        Node neighbor = map[xbound][ybound];
                        if((neighbor.getHops()==-1 || neighbor.getHops() > hops) && neighbor.getType()!=2) {    //CHECKS IF THE NODE IS NOT A WALL AND THAT IT HAS NOT BEEN EXPLORED
                            explore(neighbor, current.getX(), current.getY(), hops);
                            explored.add(neighbor); //ADD THE NODE TO THE LIST
                        }
                    }
                    xbound = current.getX()+a; 
                    ybound = current.getY();
                    if((xbound > -1 && xbound < cells) && (ybound > -1 && ybound < cells)) {    //MAKES SURE THE NODE IS NOT OUTSIDE THE GRID
                        Node neighbor = map[xbound][ybound];
                        if((neighbor.getHops()==-1 || neighbor.getHops() > hops) && neighbor.getType()!=2) {    //CHECKS IF THE NODE IS NOT A WALL AND THAT IT HAS NOT BEEN EXPLORED
                            explore(neighbor, current.getX(), current.getY(), hops);
                            explored.add(neighbor); //ADD THE NODE TO THE LIST
                        }
                    }
                    xbound = current.getX()-a; 
                    ybound = current.getY();
                    if((xbound > -1 && xbound < cells) && (ybound > -1 && ybound < cells)) {    //MAKES SURE THE NODE IS NOT OUTSIDE THE GRID
                        Node neighbor = map[xbound][ybound];
                        if((neighbor.getHops()==-1 || neighbor.getHops() > hops) && neighbor.getType()!=2) {    //CHECKS IF THE NODE IS NOT A WALL AND THAT IT HAS NOT BEEN EXPLORED
                            explore(neighbor, current.getX(), current.getY(), hops);
                            explored.add(neighbor); //ADD THE NODE TO THE LIST
                        }
                    }
                    xbound = current.getX(); 
                    ybound = current.getY()-b;
                    if((xbound > -1 && xbound < cells) && (ybound > -1 && ybound < cells)) {    //MAKES SURE THE NODE IS NOT OUTSIDE THE GRID
                        Node neighbor = map[xbound][ybound];
                        if((neighbor.getHops()==-1 || neighbor.getHops() > hops) && neighbor.getType()!=2) {    //CHECKS IF THE NODE IS NOT A WALL AND THAT IT HAS NOT BEEN EXPLORED
                            explore(neighbor, current.getX(), current.getY(), hops);
                            explored.add(neighbor); //ADD THE NODE TO THE LIST
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return explored;
        }
```

result:
[BFS without diagonal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r99mO.png)

and if with Diagonal:

```
public ArrayList<Node> exploreNeighbors1(Node current, int hops) {  //EXPLORE NEIGHBORS
            ArrayList<Node> explored = new ArrayList<Node>();   //LIST OF NODES THAT HAVE BEEN EXPLORED
            for(int a = -1; a <= 1; a++) {
                for(int b = -1; b <= 1; b++) {
                    int xbound = current.getX()+a; 
                    int ybound = current.getY()+b;
                    if((xbound > -1 && xbound < cells) && (ybound > -1 && ybound < cells)) {    //MAKES SURE THE NODE IS NOT OUTSIDE THE GRID
                        Node neighbor = map[xbound][ybound];
                        if((neighbor.getHops()==-1 || neighbor.getHops() > hops) && neighbor.getType()!=2) {    //CHECKS IF THE NODE IS NOT A WALL AND THAT IT HAS NOT BEEN EXPLORED
                            explore(neighbor, current.getX(), current.getY(), hops);
                            explored.add(neighbor); //ADD THE NODE TO THE LIST
                        }
                    }
                    xbound = current.getX()-a; 
                    ybound = current.getY()-b;
                    if((xbound > -1 && xbound < cells) && (ybound > -1 && ybound < cells)) {    //MAKES SURE THE NODE IS NOT OUTSIDE THE GRID
                        Node neighbor = map[xbound][ybound];
                        if((neighbor.getHops()==-1 || neighbor.getHops() > hops) && neighbor.getType()!=2) {    //CHECKS IF THE NODE IS NOT A WALL AND THAT IT HAS NOT BEEN EXPLORED
                            explore(neighbor, current.getX(), current.getY(), hops);
                            explored.add(neighbor); //ADD THE NODE TO THE LIST
                        }
                    }
                    xbound = current.getX(); 
                    ybound = current.getY()+b;
                    if((xbound > -1 && xbound < cells) && (ybound > -1 && ybound < cells)) {    //MAKES SURE THE NODE IS NOT OUTSIDE THE GRID
                        Node neighbor = map[xbound][ybound];
                        if((neighbor.getHops()==-1 || neighbor.getHops() > hops) && neighbor.getType()!=2) {    //CHECKS IF THE NODE IS NOT A WALL AND THAT IT HAS NOT BEEN EXPLORED
                            explore(neighbor, current.getX(), current.getY(), hops);
                            explored.add(neighbor); //ADD THE NODE TO THE LIST
                        }
                    }
                    xbound = current.getX()+a; 
                    ybound = current.getY();
                    if((xbound > -1 && xbound < cells) && (ybound > -1 && ybound < cells)) {    //MAKES SURE THE NODE IS NOT OUTSIDE THE GRID
                        Node neighbor = map[xbound][ybound];
                        if((neighbor.getHops()==-1 || neighbor.getHops() > hops) && neighbor.getType()!=2) {    //CHECKS IF THE NODE IS NOT A WALL AND THAT IT HAS NOT BEEN EXPLORED
                            explore(neighbor, current.getX(), current.getY(), hops);
                            explored.add(neighbor); //ADD THE NODE TO THE LIST
                        }
                    }
                    xbound = current.getX()-a; 
                    ybound = current.getY();
                    if((xbound > -1 && xbound < cells) && (ybound > -1 && ybound < cells)) {    //MAKES SURE THE NODE IS NOT OUTSIDE THE GRID
                        Node neighbor = map[xbound][ybound];
                        if((neighbor.getHops()==-1 || neighbor.getHops() > hops) && neighbor.getType()!=2) {    //CHECKS IF THE NODE IS NOT A WALL AND THAT IT HAS NOT BEEN EXPLORED
                            explore(neighbor, current.getX(), current.getY(), hops);
                            explored.add(neighbor); //ADD THE NODE TO THE LIST
                        }
                    }
                    xbound = current.getX(); 
                    ybound = current.getY()-b;
                    if((xbound > -1 && xbound < cells) && (ybound > -1 && ybound < cells)) {    //MAKES SURE THE NODE IS NOT OUTSIDE THE GRID
                        Node neighbor = map[xbound][ybound];
                        if((neighbor.getHops()==-1 || neighbor.getHops() > hops) && neighbor.getType()!=2) {    //CHECKS IF THE NODE IS NOT A WALL AND THAT IT HAS NOT BEEN EXPLORED
                            explore(neighbor, current.getX(), current.getY(), hops);
                            explored.add(neighbor); //ADD THE NODE TO THE LIST
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return explored;
        }
```

result:
[BFS with diagonal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmIEQ.png)

is it the same working algorithm or still different?

Comment: *"Am I doing this right"*: did you run tests? Was there any problem?

Comment: What happens when you run your code? What did you expect to happen instead? Any errors? See [ask].

Comment: Already updated the post. Thanks.